# How can i make such background using CSS only?

Tags: css, background, shapes

Any CSS savvy who have some spare time ?

I wonder how can i make such shape using CSS

[image: shape]

Thanks,
Roee

Comment: Look at this article http://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/

Comment: hello, I think you should use the canvas element in CSS3 or you you use gradients

Comment: By placing 2 CSS gradient poins really close to each other. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+50,914a4a+50;Custom

Comment: do you intend to fill this shapes with content ? If yes , it goes beyond than a simple gradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of overkill, but this technique uses borders to create triangles:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HNDDr/5/

```
#bg {
    background: black;
    height: 300px;
    width: 345px;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#bg:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 115px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 115px 300px 115px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #ef665a transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: -115px;
}
```

Comment: Well, i think this is at least the best back-compatible solution. Otherwise @winnyboy5 solution for modern browsers only is great too. Any way to combine them?

Comment: this is nice thanderful, but in my case i dont know the width and the height of the container. how can that be resolved ?

Comment: @ITomas I think you can combine them in literal sense but I don't think the CSS will gracefully degrade without the help of something like Modernizr. This is an interesting thought experiment but for practical purposes I'd recommend going with something like winnyboy5's solution since I'm assuming you want something responsive/dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using gradient background in CSS. This link will help you out.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Here is a sample:

```
background: #000000; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background:     url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIxMDAlIiB5Mj0iMTAwJSI+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjUwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzAwMDAwMCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjUwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2ZmNGQ0ZCIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgPC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD4KICA8cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2dyYWQtdWNnZy1nZW5lcmF0ZWQpIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #000000 50%, #ff4d4d 50%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(50%,#000000),  color-stop(50%,#ff4d4d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #000000 50%,#ff4d4d 50%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #000000 50%,#ff4d4d 50%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #000000 50%,#ff4d4d 50%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #000000 50%,#ff4d4d 50%); /* W3C */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000',   endColorstr='#ff4d4d',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using css border tricks and a layer acting as background you may accomplish this
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to fill this with content , you may want to use `transform`:

Example with `skewx(-15deg)` on the full height of a page : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lvoaf/

HTML to draw 2 boxes aside each other:

```
<section>
  <div>
  left side
</div>
</section>
<section>
<div>
  right side
</div>
</section>
```

and CSS that can go along :

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:#FF4D4D;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  display:table;
  padding-left:10%;
  width:80%;
  background:#333;  
  border-spacing:0;
}
section {
  display:table-cell;
  width:50%;
  color:white;
  background:#333;
  transform:skewx(-15deg);
  height:100%;
}
section + section {
  background:#FF4D4D;
}
section > div {
  transform:skewx(15deg); 
  transform-origin:bottom right;
  min-height:100%;
  padding:1em;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background-color:inherit;
}
section + section > div {
  transform-origin:top left;
}
```

---

or a simple gradient http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FdhyG/

```
  html {
   background:linear-gradient(
    -50deg, 
    #FF4D4D 50%,
    #333333 50%
   );
  min-height:100%;}
```